# netbeans debugging issue in yii php

Tags: debugging, netbeans, yii, breakpoints

I have net-beans 7.3.1, and a project on YII-Framework, i have put up a break point in Site Controller, unfortunately it looks like it is not hitting break-point at all, just to add i have IIS-8 on local host and Apache on localhost:8080, i have done relevant setting in the net-beans to operate it in debugging mode through run configuration. But i am unable to debug it, since application is not getting halted on the break point, although it gets opened up through net-beans.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: do you have xdebug installed on php ?

Comment: when i go for debug, it says 'Waiting for Connection (net beans-x debug)' i am not able to understand why it is not connecting with x debug, hoping it will give me some clue to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok well as a start try verifying that you have xdebug installed by running

```
php -i | grep "xdebug"
```

If it doesn't return any thing then you need to install the `php5-xdebug` package using the method appropriate to your operating system.
Then you need to check the `xdebug.ini` or `php.ini` file and [follow the help on this page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_on_Linux)

When you are done, you either restart `apache` ( if you have apache installed), or restart `php5-fpm` / `php5-cgi` ( if you have either installed )

Comment: I have done everything, starting from updating php.ini in "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin" and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13, here are the changes                                                                        zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost:8080
xdebug.remote_port=8080                                          my phpinfo on provides right information about xdebug.

Comment: I have spent quite amount of time in resolving it, don't know where is the problem

Comment: my netbeans still show waiting for connection netbeans-xdebug at right bottom.

Comment: did you change the port number to 8080 in netbeans? it's default is 9000

Comment: I tried with 9000 , 9001 and 8080 ,these changes i did in apache, php and netbeans php debugging settings but nothing worked its quite frustrating

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but do you restart apache after changing the configuration ?

Comment: yes everytime through wamp "Restart All Services", as well as tried with rebooting computer also